# Winform hangs with async-await click event

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have following Click event which loads **`5000`** records from database, and assign to text box as:

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var studentsasync = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/students");

            TxtStudents.Text = "Data is Loading...";

            var students = await studentsasync;
            TxtStudents.Text = students;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
        }     
}
```

However, I observed, when I click the button and the `Form` freezes until I get response from server and load into textbox. If I try to change position of window, couldn't happen, however when data loads and then goes to position where last mouse release.

Comment: I think its the assignment to `TxtStudents.Text` that causes the issue. You really need to display 5000(!) students in, what is it, a TextBox all at once?

Comment: @PeterBons Even after changing to GridView and only 50 records, I can see it hangs for a big. Not works as smooth as expected.